# Routing and GetVirtualPath problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm using MVC 2 Preview2, with two areas in a single project. When I use RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(this.viewContext.RequestContext, null) from inside an area, I got the virtual path to the first area instead. Except for this, areas are working pretty well.

What can I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in MVC 2 use **GetVirtualPathForArea** instead of GetVirtualPath