# RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath with route data asp.net MVC 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to get a URL from my routes table.  Here is the method.

```
private static void RedirectToRoute(ActionExecutingContext context, string param)
    {
        var actionName = context.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
        var controllerName = context.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;

        var rc = new RequestContext(context.HttpContext, context.RouteData);
        string url = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(rc, new RouteValueDictionary(new { actionName = actionName, controller = controllerName, parameter = param })).VirtualPath;
        context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(url, true);

    }
```

I'm trying to map it to.  However RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(rc, new RouteValueDictionary(new { actionName = actionName, controller = controllerName, parameter = param })) keeps giving me null.  Any thoughts?

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "default3",                                              // Route name
            "{parameter}/{controller}/{action}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { parameter= "parameterValue", controller = "Home", action = "Index" }

        );
```

I know I can use redirectToAction and other methods, but I would like to change the URL in the browser with new routedata.

Answer (score 0):

x try RouteCollection.GetVirtualPathForArea instead, worked for me

x [Routing and GetVirtualPath problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627423/routing-and-getvirtualpath-problem)

Actually this was not any different, the issue was that the area in the route values was blank and we are still using the old AreaViewEngine from way back

As a temp fix we change the area if blank to "root", and this then it all works fine